# Simple example to understand Websockets in java

Tags: java, eclipse, websocket

I am new to java development, can anybody help me with web sockets basic example.
I searched the net but all the examples are very complex. Please help me out guys.

Comment: If you are new to `JAVA` it may be difficult to find a simple example.

Comment: If you have a (specific) question about one of the examples, we'd be happy to explain how it works. Please post the example and explain what part is unclear to you.

Comment: If you are new to Java you should learn the basics before trying the advanced stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer :

https://gist.github.com/chitan/3063774

There is example program inside the tomcats examples folder, Try it out.